# Rendering a framebuffer to texture wont work

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am trying to create a depth map in OpenGL and for some reason the framebuffer wont write to the texture, I tried multiple things to fix it but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is what I did:

This is the generation of the framebuffer and the texture:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &_DepthMapFBO);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _DepthMapFBO);

glGenTextures(1, &_DepthMapTex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _DepthMapTex);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, DEPTH_TEXTURE_WIDTH, DEPTH_TEXTURE_HEIGHT, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT); 
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL_COMPARE_REF_TO_TEXTURE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC, GL_LEQUAL);

//glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, _DepthMapTex, 0);
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, _DepthMapTex, 0);

glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

(In the above I tried replacing `glTexImage2D` with `glTexStorage2D` and I tried replace `glFramebufferTexture` with `glFramebufferTexture2D`, both didn't work)

Then (There  is stuff before this but they work find, I checked) I rendered the framebuffer as follows:

```
_DepthProgram.Use();
// Setting uniforms here
glViewport(0, 0, DEPTH_TEXTURE_WIDTH, DEPTH_TEXTURE_HEIGHT);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _DepthMapFBO);
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
// Rendering the scene here
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

These are the shaders I use:

(Vertex)

```
#version 410 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 Position;

uniform mat4 LightSpaceMatrix;
uniform mat4 Model;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = LightSpaceMatrix * Model * vec4(Position, 1.0);
}
```

(Fragment)

```
#version 410 core

void main()
{
    // gl_FragDepth = 0.0;
}
```

I tried rendering the texture to a plane and it came out totally white (I Checked there was supposed to be other values), **As you can see in the fragment shader, I tried to explicitly write to the `gl_FragDepth` but it didn't change the texture, it kept it white (1.0)**.

I looked all over the internet and looked at [learnopengl.com](https://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-Lighting/Shadows/Shadow-Mapping) and everybody seem to be doing the same as me, did I miss something?

(***I double checked and I am rendering the texture to the plane right, I replaced the `glBindTexture` with another one and it rendered the texture***)

If I am missing some information please let me know.

EDIT: By the way, I don't get any error with `glGetError`.

Comment: Did you check for framebuffer completeness?

Comment: @BDL Yeah I did, it returns `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE`

Comment: How do you access the texture? Are you using the correct shadow sampler form with a proper reference value?

Comment: @derhass I am assuming you are talking about the shader in the second pass, I tried using both `sampler2D` and `sampler2DShadow` both didn't work. (The `sampler2DShadow` game me this message: `Sample object 0 is bound to non-depth texture 0, yet it is used with a program that uses a shadow sampler.`

Comment: Well, there is something wrong with your GL state for the second pass.

Comment: @derhass I tried to figure out what is going wrong but I didn't find anything, is there anything wrong with what I posted? any of the snippet of code I posted is wrong?

Comment: @derhass How come its a problem with the GL state in the `second` pass if I can render the scene and just the texture of the first pass wont show? (As i mentioned, I tried different textures and it works with them)

Comment: @Zik332 what gfx card you got? older Intel HDs are not capable of rendering to texture (no errors are thrown but there is no rendering either).